# What does "kloane Hex" mean?

Tags: meaning, bavarian

It can be seen as body tattoos or written on the cake hanging in the neck of pretty girls serving beer, for example at Oktoberfest. See pictures [here.](http://www.google.de/search?num=10&hl=de&site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=kloane%20hex&oq=kloane%20hex)

My guess would be that Hex refers to witch (Hexe), although I am not quite sure what happened to the -e, perhaps it's simply dropped (like in ich hab).

What does the adjective mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Kloane Hex

is

> Kleine Hexe

in bavarian German.

It is used in parts of Austria as well (according to comment in southern parts of Lower-Austria).

Comment: It's Bavarian, not Austrian. In Austria "klane Hex" (without o between k and a) is more common. You also find "klans Hexi", "klanes Hexi" and "klan(e)s Hexerl". - It all means "little witch" and is a pet name for young girls and young ladies.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Thanks for the addition.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Austrian German is a [Bavarian language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_language). I'd say there is not much difference between *kloan* and *klaan* from a linguistic view.

Comment: +1 and thanks. Had a good laugh :)

Comment: I've heard the use of "kloane" also in Styria, Burgenland and the southern parts of Lower-Austria. So the assumption that this term is not used in Austria (as opposed to only in Bavaria) being wrong, is wrong. It's just not used in all of Austria.

Comment: @MacLemon Fair enough. Edited my answer.

Comment: Let's say, it is middle Bavarian: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte#Mittelbairisch